# multiple column price range sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, range, multiple-columns

Not able to solve this query:

Want to search product with category, subcategory , lower price range and upper price range

```
select * from product p join category c 
ON(p.category_id=c.category_id) where p.category=? and p.sub_category_id=?
and lower_price_limit between ? and ? or upper_price_limit between ? and ?
```

For example: A product range from `200 to 250` and pass `220 to 230` this doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add parenthesis on your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product p 
JOIN category c 
    ON p.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE
    p.category = ? 
    AND p.sub_category_id = ? 
    AND (
        lower_price_limit BETWEEN ? AND ? 
        OR upper_price_limit BETWEEN ? AND ?
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :-

```
 select * from product p join category c 
    ON p.category_id=c.category_id where p.category=? and p.sub_category_id=?
    and (lower_price_limit between ? and ? or upper_price_limit between ? and ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from product p 
join category c ON p.category_id=c.category_id 
where p.category=? and p.sub_category_id=? and 
      (lower_price_limit between ? and ? or upper_price_limit between ? and ?)
```